# ProgressRing is not showing while the app runs

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a 'Universal App' for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1

I need to add a `ProgressRing` control to my page, because there is a task which takes some time to complete and I should notify the user that the app is loading data. So I followed the instruction on MDSN in the following link:

[To create an indeterminate progress ring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780651.aspx)
and they stated what I exactly need:

> **4. Adding an indeterminate progress ring**
>
> When you can't estimate how much work remains to finish a task and the
>   task does block user interaction, use an indeterminate progress ring.
>   An indeterminate progress ring shows an animate sequence of dots
>   moving in a circle.

The problem is that the `ProgressRing` doesn't play the animation of "loading", when I insert `prog.IsActive = true;` before the code that starts the task

If I comment the Task lines of code, it plays.

XAML :

```
 <ProgressRing x:Name="prog" Margin="435,349,388,181" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontFamily6}" FontSize="25" />
```

C#:

```
 private void LevelTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        prog.IsActive = true;
        CheckNav(sender);
    }

private void CheckNav(object sender)
    {
        TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
        GameSetter game = new GameSetter();
        game.Level = (int)TextDict[tb];
        if (!LevelsArr[game.Level]) return;
        if (!goToLeader)
        {            
            prog.IsActive = false;
            CallNav(true, game);
        }
        else
        {
            prog.IsActive = false;
            CallNav(false, game);
        }    
    }

    private void CallNav(bool b,GameSetter g)
    { 
        if(b)  Frame.Navigate(typeof(Game8), g);
        else Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), g);
    }
```

**Note:** The Task that runs uses `Dictionary`, `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData`, and `Navigation` for another page in the end.

Comment: hum, let me guess, `GameSetter game = new GameSetter();` takes a significant amount of time, right?

Comment: @kennyzx not exactly , the constructor does nothing actually , and it only got 3 propeties.

Comment: so after you start the progress ring, you stop it immediately by setting `prog.IsActive = false;` - since there seems to be no step that is time consuming.

Comment: @kennyzx i came up with an idea , to implement a timer to start when the `ProgressRing` is started , and after 0.5 Seconds it will start the task , and that did the trick , but still , it's not the way i prefer to code.

Comment: OK, that should work, at least the ProgressRing will be visible for half a second. But first examine the performance of the code, calculating how much time each line takes using a `Stopwatcher`. If game loading is actually not slow, you don't need to have this `ProgressRing`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code block in every function too if Progressing inDeterminate mode always open:

```
  #region Progress Ring Start
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Waiter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // Progress ring name is Waiter.
            });

            #endregion
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            CheckNav(sender); // Your process



            #region Progress Ring Finish
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                Waiter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // Progress ring name is Waiter.

            });
            #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

The flaw in your code (except the fact that it's probably nearly instant anyway, as notes @kennyzx), is that you need the `LevelTap` method to return for the UI to be updated. And when the method returns, you've already set the `ProgressRing.IsActive` property back to false, which means nothing is displayed at all.

One simple way to fix that is to use the async `Task.Yield` method to give the UI thread a chance to run:

```
private async void LevelTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    prog.IsActive = true;

    await Task.Yield();

    CheckNav(sender);
}
```

But almost nothing will be shown since your code shouldn't take long to execute. If you really want to force the indicator to be displayed for 0.5 seconds, you can do something like:

```
private async void LevelTap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    prog.IsActive = true;

    await Task.Delay(500);

    CheckNav(sender);
}
```

Comment: you two didn't understand what i was trying to say , the 0.5 second is the amount of time the app wait so it can start the task , so it would take 0.5 seconds + task time = (something like 3 seconds) , i think it's reasonable to make a `ProgressRing` for such period

Comment: @GabourX I see. Then, does the `Task.Yield` solve your issue?

Comment: in my uwp app works perfectly fine in desktop but in mobile, instead of showing a ring, a blank page is displayed.

Comment: @ravikumar It seems to be a different issue, you should post a new question